# LSI MegaRAID 84016e reboots server

Tags: lsi, megaraid

Have problem with my LSI 84016e. Have mobo Supermicro x8sil-f. Have installed RAID adapter, have booted to Debian 7, have created RAID10 and started just simple dd write test. Several beeps and server goes to reboot. In dmesg/messages logs Buffer IO error. In LSI logs nothing critical.

Any ideas? Now 3 days testing raid with fio/dd/badblocks ... all works good... not sure what to do...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it could be temp related on the 84016e card. I would try a fan, 80mm to 120mm blowing directly on the card.